# Android Studio: project-level error list show incorrect errors

Tags: android, android-studio, syntax-error

This started happening immediately after i updated from
Android Studio (Girrafe) to Android Studio (Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1)

The project-level errorslist doesn't align with file-level errorlist, the project-level list makes up imaginary errors, the file-level one is always correct.

the errors don't affect my build process (it's purely visual) but makes it hard to see a full view of all the errors in my project.

check image for screeshot of the issue:
[image]

Comment: @Robert the errors themselves aren't relevant as the issue is purely visual and the errors are not real (the app builds without issues or errors in the logs)